# Register vs RegisterInstance vs RegisterSingleton in Prism 7 DI

Tags: c#, prism

I am trying to register a service for DI in Prism 7. I find that all of the following methods work, which is the correct way to do it? What is the case for each?

```
public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    static OpenAppService openAppService = new OpenAppService();

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IOpenAppService>(openAppService);

        containerRegistry.Register<IFacebookLoginService, FacebookLoginService>();

        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppleSignInService, AppleSignInService>();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, what each of these methods does totally depends on the actual container used, especially when you go beyond the totally trivial things. That's probably the main cause why there's no documentation for this stuff.

That being said...

- `Register` says that the given service should be used when the given interface is injected, and that a *new* instance will be created for each single injection.
- `RegisterSingleton` differs in that the same instance is used for *all* injections.
- `RegisterInstance` is the same as `RegisterSingleton`, but you have to provide an instance.

> which is the correct way to do it? What is the case for each?

So, most of the time services are registered as singletons, because you want viewmodels to be able to communicate through the service. Example: the `EventAggregator` - when one view models publishes an event, you expect others to receive it, which is only possible if they subscribe using the same instance as the publisher publishes on. A WCF client, though, doesn't need to be a singleton, because the communication happens on the server side.

You don't want to register instances because this mixes up registration and resolving, and you have to make absolutely sure that *all* dependencies of the instance have been registered already when creating the instance to register it (through a call to `Resolve`, which in itself has a touch of evil). This is less of a problem if you register everything in one method, but becomes a lot more of a headache if you have multiple (interdependent) modules.

Comment: Thank you for thoroughly explaining this! I am sure other people would also find this informative as I couldn't find concrete answers searching for this.

Comment: @DanSiegel can you give us a hint? In the code, at least, there's nothing https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/src/Prism.Core/Ioc